# Apply stipple pattern as texture OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, texture-mapping, stipple

Is there a way you can apply a stipple pattern (for example the fly stipple pattern) as a **texture** to an object (e.g. within the `glBindTexture` method)?

Comment: Does this help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23444/A-Simple-OpenGL-Stipple-Polygon-Example-EP-OpenGL

Comment: @enhzflep unfortunately not. That applies a stipple pattern to a polygon. Im trying to add a texture to the object. Sort of like applying a bitmap image as a texture to the object, however instead, using a stipple pattern.

Comment: Is there any reason not to simply texture map it with an image of a stipple pattern? That seems like the easiest approach so long as your model has UVs.